# Is the only way to raise my Strength by drinking a potion of Strength?

Tags: brogue

As the title sugests, how else, if there is another way, can I raise my strength in Brogue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't any other way. Keep in mind that using scrolls of enchantment on weapons and armor lowers their strength requirement, as well as adding bonus.